# why array_push don't work inside foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, array-push

i have this code for file update and i need to put the files path in response array. but my array is empty:

```
    $response = array();
    if (file_exists($directorSerie)) {
        if(is_array($_FILES)) {     
            foreach ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] as $name => $value){
                if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$name])) {
                    $sourcePath = $_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name'][$name];
                    $targetPath = $directorSerieString.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'][$name];
                    array_push($response, $targetPath);                             


                    if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
                        $success = "success";                   

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
exit(json_encode($response));
```

Comment: Have you put a logging statement at the top of each `if` and `foreach` block to ensure that it is being entered? Have you tried logging `$targetPath` to see if it what you expected?

Comment: Simplier (more common) 'array_push' syntax: $response[] = $targetPath;

Comment: using $response[] = $targetPath; just give the same result: empty array

Comment: can you elaborate on the "logging statement" matter ?

Answer (score -2):

array_push() works on foreach.
I sugest you to put dubug to found where is the mistakes.
You could put var_dump($var) after level of your code, like this:

```
if (file_exists($directorSerie)) {
  var_dump($directorSerie);
```

Next...

```
if(is_array($_FILES)) {  
  var_dump($_FILES)
```

Next

```
foreach ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'] as $name => $value){
   var_dump( $name ,$value);
```

up until you discover...

Comment: a comment worthy observation, not answer material.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the code works, the file is uploaded as it should, only in the console i get an empty array